# Vote for the 2014 Winter Game Jam logo!

Tags: discussion, gamejam-2014-winter

We of the chatrooms have decided that we wanted to make a new logo for the Winter Game Jam, honoring the amazing hats that SE and Elias Stein (the artist) have provided for us this winter. We are going to be posting possible logos in the next week or so, so keep visiting this post until the jam, and vote on your favorites. Anyone in the community is welcome to submit their own version of the logo, the original is right here!

[image: Original Logo]

Please, no downvotes. Only upvotes for the ones that you like!

Answers to this question are to include only the picture and a short, 1-2 sentence description.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe someone can take this and do something nicer with it:

[image]

It's supposed to be something like a snowflake.

Comment: Goddamit Byte, you classy upstaging bastard you :D

Comment: Somebody suggested a fractal theme already right? Right?

Answer (score 8):

And here is my Snowflake GDSE complete with snowman

[image: Snowflake GDSE]

With transparency and slightly larger:

[image: Transparent Version]

Now with more jam:

[image: Jam Version]

Comment: Perhaps transparent background though if this one wins :)

Comment: I agree @Dave. Also, where is the jam?

Comment: @Pip in the jar.

Comment: I have a feeling I'd like this even without anything in the middle. Good job!

Comment: Look. At. Byte's.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Logo made by Pip]

This logo is simple, but exemplifies the winter and our hosts, the SE staff.

Comment: No "winter is coming" hat? :P

Comment: @JoshPetrie I tried it, but it didn't fit the dimensions of the jar very well.... the santa hat fit only slightly better